# Adding a class to ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, extends

i'm having some trouble adding the elements from my class "Row" to my class "Table". Class Table extends ArrayList so each element of the arrayList should contain a class Row.
If i create a class Table and run the addApplicant(Row app) method manually i am able to add a Row. However i would like a Row to automatically add itself to Class Table as soon as it is created.
Here is my code so far:
The Table class:

```
public class Table extends ArrayList<Row>{

public String appArray[];

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Table
 */
public Table()
{
}

public void addApplicant(Row app)
{
    add(app);
}

public void listArray() //Lists the Array[]
{
    for(int i = 0; i<appArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(appArray[i]);
    }
}}
```

The Row Class:

```
public class Row{

private String appNumber;
private String name;
private String date;
private String fileLoc;
private String country;
public ArrayList<String> applicant;

public Row(String appNumber, String name, String date, String fileLoc, String country)
{
    this.appNumber = appNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.fileLoc = fileLoc;
    this.country = country;
    applicant = new ArrayList<String>();
    applicant.add(appNumber);
    applicant.add(name);
    applicant.add(date);
    applicant.add(fileLoc);
    applicant.add(country);
}

private void convertToString()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<applicant.size(); i++)
        {
            String appStr = applicant.toString();
        }
}}
```

Any ideas of what i'm missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add the Table instance as parameter to row constructor. than call from the constructor of the row to : table.AddApplicantRow(this)

Comment: It is bad way to extend ArrayList in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no reference to a table class. What you can do, is request that the Table object is passed into the constructor, so your constructor will look like this:

```
 public Row(String appNumber, String name, String date, String fileLoc, String country, Table table)
```

and call

```
table.addApplicant(this);
```

When you're finished loading information into the row Object. That will add a reference to this row object into your table :)

Comment: Remember to mark it as the answer for future readers :) and on another note, using Inheritance for this sort of thing isn't the right way to go about it. Because you only require a small part of the ArrayList class' functionality, you should use [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Composition)

Comment: I'll mark it as soon as the 10 minute block has passed. I'll look into composition. Thanks again for all your help.